# generalizing a regex

Tags: java, regex

Using the regex

```
(^([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])$)
```

to validate ipv4 addresses works just fine, however I was wondering is it possible to have it so that the regular expression works for string inputs such as

63.88.73.253test

where 63.88.73.253 is what the regex groups?

Comment: You may want to learn the basics of regex before asking a regex question. This is a pretty simple fix. (remove the `$`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**
In your regular expression the `$`at the end signals that nothing may come after this expression. Simply remove the `$` so that you have `^([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])`. Additionally make sure you are looking for an occurrence and not for a match.

**Option 2:**
Assuming you want the text to be part of the regular expression you can remove the `$` and instead add a `.*` which will look for any character (assuming you specified that whitespace should be treated as a normal character). This would result in `^([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]).*`. Here you can safely look for a match.

**Note:** The outer brackets that you used in your question are unnecessary. Also the start of line `^` prevents any whitespace (actually any characters, for that matter) before the IP, which you might not want.